# Should I delete my question in this weird catch-22 situation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626126/electron-unable-to-drag-files-after-installing-communication-with-python-scrip). At first it was more general, because I didn't understand how changing backend stuff caused issues with the front-end UI elements that were completely unrelated. I later realized that the root of the problem was running [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) through an administrator PowerShell window. I quickly edited the question to reflect that, then googled and immediately found out the answer in [Electron's issues page on GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/5243).

Usually when I answer myself, I either leave the question if I think it has value for others or delete it if I think it doesn't. This is a weird one though, because I don't know which to choose - if someone else encounters this issue, he'll either figure out what's the cause and immediately find the solution on GitHub just like I did or have used administrator-PowerShell for completely unrelated reasons to my own and probably won't find my question at all.

In other words: my question only has value for people who don't know the cause of the problem, meaning they can't find my question, and the people who figure out the cause of the problem will be able to find my question, but it won't pose any value to them.

What's the thing to do here?

Comment: You could change your question _back_ into the more general version, and then answer it. In your answer, you can explain the actual cause behind the issue. This way, those who should be seeing your question will find it.

Comment: There are many existing Q+A about this drag+drop restriction, we only need one for every UI related [tag].  So yay, [electron] is now covered as well.  All you have to do is check if it not a duplicate.  It is, you can now dup-vote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862626/electron-file-dragover-gives-a-crossed-out-circle-without-events-fired) as well.  That's a good thing of course.  Consider making the answer a bit more generic, all that matters is that the app runs elevated.  How that happened isn't that important.

Comment: How ironic asked by yuvi and last edited by yivi.

Comment: @JonH isn't that the opposite of ironic?

Comment: Honestly, I just learned something today by reading your question... And I think your question has value but you definitely have to change the title to make it reachable by a search engine.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Well, maybe something like : "Unable to drag and drop in a windows admin-run electron application" would be a bit more appropriate... it's up to you.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I did edit it to that, but that's on the nose. That's exactly what I'm not sure about because titling it like that means giving the answer as well, whereas the first title I used is how I got into the problem which might help more people find it. It's kind of convoluted but I hope I'm explaining it well enough

Comment: Yes I also felt this way... I totally understand what you are explaining. One thing seems clear to me : i don't think python belongs in the title. Again, it is an opinion... Hmmm, not an easy struggle

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To me, the resolution fits the **"resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers"** close reason.
It appears that you simply forgot that you cannot drag and drop between windows belonging to processes run under different accounts in Windows.

So, it's not even a programming problem, or a problem specific to a programming tool. Neither is there anything particularly valuable in your specific manifestation of it.

The question is thus fit to be deleted.

Comment: I didn't forget as much as never knew. I used to develop in a linux environment in the past, working in Windows is new (and frustrating) to me (and this isn't different accounts btw). It's definitely not a programming problem, but it is a problem that people who develop in electron might encounter. I dunno, I tend to agree with the general notion which is why I wasn't sure if to delete or not. You seem to have the majority of the vote so I'll take that as my answer

Comment: oh uh... someone linked another similar question to mine as a duplicate (since it didn't have an answer and mine did). I can't delete it now hehehehe that's hilarious

Comment: @yuvi You can ask a moderator to look into this and link to this discussion. Apparently, some users think that this resolution _will_ help other users and that includes some of the moderators. So, let them resolve this between themselves first.

Answer (score 3):

You can do one of two things:

- Encapsulate what you've found into an answer and explain what it is.  If you use that source material, **be sure you reference it and credit the actual answerer**.
- Delete the question.  In its current state it won't count against you.  But you have to act quick; if it gets an answer on it, deleting it will harm you *more*.

Comment: Harm me more? What? reputation wise? Becasue that's not really something I care a lot about, to be honest

Comment: Deleting a question with an answer on it counts heavily against you on a potential question ban.

Comment: I didn't know that. Well, I chose the first route anyway, I think it does have some value. It's very niche, but I dunno. Maybe someone will go through the same route I did and this'll help him

Comment: I don't think a 10k+ user has much to worry about in the way of a question ban. That certainly shouldn't be your primary motivation for deciding whether or not to delete a question. The relevant issue is, might someone else benefit from having this question answered?

Comment: @CodyGray Yeah that's my line of thinking too